# How did they show Worldedit brush NBT tags in this video?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I was watching a video to jog my memory about using brushes in Worldedit, when [at this point](https://youtu.be/FZj4-Y2qvm8?t=234) the author went into the inventory and hovered over the brushes.

[image]

As you can see all the data of each brush are visible, while I can only see this even with F3+H on.

[image]

The `/data get entity @s SelectedItem` command displays exactly the same data. I thought the author used the NBT Tooltip mod, but that's not the case.
Someone asked this 9 months ago

> I've been wondering how you get all the brush details to display in
> the HUD when you mouse over brushes.  It looks like json.  I asked in
> the WorldEdit discord but they were not sure.

but sadly MegRae never replied.

Does anyone have any idea what mod was used? It would be very useful for someone like me who always forgets which brush is linked to which tool, or even if there is a brush.

My setup: Minecraft 1.19.3/Fabric, Modpack "Fabulously Optimized", Worldedit 7.2.13

Comment: It would be useful to copy a little cropped screenshot of the video into the question, to show what you mean and in case the video gets taken down (now or in 10 years).

Comment: After checking a few suspicions, I think it's just another mod. Googling "Minecraft mod NBT item tooltips" or so gives a bunch of fitting results. Someone could now compose them all to see which one was likely the one in the video or you could just use the one you prefer.